# Two columns, auto filled, with an image on top of the second column (magazine-like layout)

Tags: html, css

I displayed text in a two columns layout, with `column-count` and `column-fill: auto` so that it fills completely the first column before going to the second.

I also need to add an illustration at the top right (top of the second column). With a `position: fixed`, the text won't wrap around the image but will hide underneath it. I tried `float` combinations with no success.

How would you approach this ? Thanks !

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="description">
      <div>
        longish text
      </div>

      <figure>
        <img class="illustration"
            src="data:image:{{ p.id }}">
      </figure>

    </div>
  </div>





.main {
  margin-top: 2cm;
  padding: 0 1cm 0cm 1cm;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2em;
  column-fill: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.produit-title {
    color: firebrick;
    padding: 2cm 1cm 0cm 1cm;
}

img.illustration {
  margin-top: 0.1cm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 5cm;
  max-width: 11cm;
  border: solid 0.04cm;
  border-color: firebrick;
}
```

expected result:

[image]

(edit) the text can be of variable length, but I would like the layout to stay the same. A short text can stop at the first column (role of `colum-fill: auto`), but the image would still be on the right.

Comment: have you looked into CSS Grid? Also you want the text in the second column to not wrap but just lay underneath the image? Wouldn't that disrupt readability?

Comment: is your column width and column count fixed, or variable as well?

Comment: For what I know (bootstrap's grid experience), I don't see how CSS grid would allow to distribute the text between columns. What would disrupt readability ? The image will generally take all the width, and we're used to this disposition in newspapers.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini mmh it's pretty fixed, I need two columns and they should be the same width with different text. When there's not enough text it can stop inside column 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an easy task at all. You can sort of hack it though, **if** your images have a fixed height:

```css
div {
  max-width:420px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

div p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150px">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro id sequi rem aspernatur dolore expedita quia. Atque amet enim aliquid rem eligendi quibusdam rerum, consequuntur tenetur eum, error vero impedit?orem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro id sequi rem aspernatur dolore expedita quia. Atque amet enim aliquid rem eligendi quibusdam rerum, consequuntur tenetur eum, error vero impedit?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro id sequi rem aspernatur dolore expedita quia. Atque amet enim aliquid rem eligendi quibusdam rerum, consequuntur tenetur eum, error vero impedit?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro id sequi rem aspernatur dolore expedita quia. Atque amet enim aliquid rem eligendi quibusdam rerum, consequuntur tenetur eum, error vero impedit?</p>
 </div>
```

The trick is to absolute position the image in the container then pull the text back up by setting a positive padding on the container and negative margin on the first paragrash, both equal number to the image height.

This is one of those things that definitely **should** be easier.

Comment: so I should  pre-compute my paragraphs, split my text (coming from a variable) into a larger and a smaller string ? That may be doable. (btw I don't think SO's "run code snippet" is showing what you want).

Comment: @Ehvince wut? I didn't said anything about pre-computing or splitting :s
 
And the snippet is working as intended (at least on Firefox, Chrome, and IE11). Wasn't that 2-columns layout with the image on the right one at the top what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Indeed, works beautifully on FF at least > 43 ! Ok sorry, the thing is that my text comes from a variable, replaced by the framework, so I need to take care of that. You put me on the right track anyway, thanks ! (this may be *the* answer then, will fiddle around a bit more).

Comment: Hello again, if you want to have fun adding a border and a (longish) caption, be my guest :) https://jsfiddle.net/918kn7pb/ when I use a figure + figcaption and a surrounding div or span that would position them the image goes a bit out of its place, the caption comes over the text… thanks for ideas maybe !

Comment: @Ehvince that's because figure has a default margin applied by the browser. Add figure{margin:0;} to your CSS and it should work. Then you might want to add the height of the figcaption to the previous margin-top and padding top hack

Answer (score 1):

Can't you structure the html like this?  Making sure that the image is positioned relatively inside the div?

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="description">
        <div>
            longish text
            <img class="illustration" src="data:image:{{ p.id }}">
            more text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: If this does not work for you then as I see it you need to either decide where your image is always going to be e.g. always open your article with image followed by text and then you can position as required, or adopt some widely unsupported solution such as regions (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/regions/adobe/).

Comment: You mean to manually put the right quantity of text before and after ? I can't, the text varies, it is constructed with variables by a framework.

Comment: Damn css regions look like exactly what I need, but they are indeed [largely unsupported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions).

Comment: Yes, the last time I read an article about flowing text like this the writer essentially said don't do it - the web is not a magazine, which is true but it would be nice have the options to do it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Came upon this stack when trying to find a better solution than the one I went with which was the following. Only advantage to the accepted answer is it doesn't require absolute positioning. Still need to know the height of the image.
Note: the image *does* have to come before the text.

```css
.columns {
  columns: 2;
}
.image {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  column-span: all;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.text {
  margin-top: -100px; /* height of image */
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare. Magna eget est lorem ipsum dolor. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Nam aliquam sem et tortor. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget. Tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc. Condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada.

Dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae. Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Arcu risus quis varius quam quisque id diam vel. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id. Placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis. Quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero volutpat.
</div>
<div>
```